# XSLT - Extract values from XML where element names are in external document

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

### Input data

There are two XML documents: `cars.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Cars>
  <Car Make="Cadillac" Country="U.S.A.">
    <Options>
      <Airbag Price="100" />
      <CruiseControl Price="200" />
      <SeatBelts Price="300" />
    </Options>
  </Car>
  <Car Make="Volvo" Country="Sweden">
    <Options>
      <Airbag Price="50" />
      <SeatBelts Price="75" />
    </Options>
  </Car>
</Cars>
```

and `options.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Options>
  <Option><Name>Airbag</Name></Option>
  <Option><Name>CruiseControl</Name></Option>
  <Option><Name>FalconWings</Name></Option>
</Options>
```

I realize that the `Options` elements in `cars.xml` should have been defined like this:

```
<Option Name="Airbag" Price="100" />
```

But `cars.xml` is an input file from an external source.  I *do* however have control over the format of the `options.xml` file.

### Desired output

I want to create a .csv containing the cars in `cars.xml` and the prices for the options that are listed in `options.xml`.

```
# Make,Country,Airbag,CruiseControl,FalconWings
Cadillac,U.S.A.,100,200,N/A
Volvo,Sweden,50,N/A,N/A
```

### Question

How do I get the stylesheet to print the options listed in `options.xml` with the price in `cars.xml` (or N/A if the car does not have the option)?

Comment: I would suggest you use a **key** for performing lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like

```
<xsl:variable name="options" select="doc('Options.xml')//Name" as="xs:string*"/>

<!-- header line -->
...
<xsl:value-of select="$options" separator="."/>
...

<xsl:for-each select="Cars/Car">
   <xsl:variable name="car" select="."/>
   <!-- detail line -->
   ...
   <xsl:for-each select="$options">
     <xsl:variable name="o" select="$car/Option/*[name()=current()]">
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="exists($o)">
         <xsl:value-of select="',(' || name($o) || '=)' || $o/@Price"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>,N/A</xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Quite readable, and works for me.  Inside the `when` I use:

    `<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>`
    `<xsl:value-of select="$o/@Price" />`

to get the output that I want.

Comment: There are a few typos in the answer: the separator in the header line is a dot iso. a comma, the value of variable `o` should be set using `/Options/` and terminated using `/>`.

Comment: Can I edit your answer (fix typos, add left-out code)?

Comment: @Roger If you want.

Answer (score 2):

I like using `xsl:value-of` to output a line of a csv:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:param name="options-url" select="'options.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="options" select="doc($options-url)//Name"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Make', 'Country', $options" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Cars/Car"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Car">
        <xsl:value-of select="@*, for $o in $options return ((current()/Options/*[name() = $o]/@Price, 'N/A')[1])" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get

```
Make,Country,Airbag,CruiseControl,FalconWings
Cadillac,U.S.A.,100,200,N/A
Volvo,Sweden,50,N/A,N/A
```

Comment: Looks pretty advanced.  When I try this, I do get three option prices for both cars, but they're all `N/A`.

Comment: @Roger, I have edited the answer and added the output I get. Make sure the parameter for that secondary file is set correctly.

Comment: The file `options.xml` is read, because my header line is correct.  I will try to understand your `value-of` expression when I get home.

Comment: This solution works fine. I didn't work yesterday because I didn't make an exact copy. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Michael's suggestion, I ended up with this stylesheet that produces the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
   version="2.0">

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:variable name="options" select="doc('options.xml')//Name" as="xs:string*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">

      <!-- header line -->
      <xsl:text># Make,Country,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$options" separator=","/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text> <!-- newline -->

      <xsl:for-each select="Cars/Car">
         <xsl:variable name="car" select="."/>

         <!-- detail line -->
         <xsl:value-of select="@Make"/>
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="@Country"/>

         <xsl:for-each select="$options" >
            <xsl:variable name="o" select="$car/Options/*[name()=current()]"/>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="exists($o)">
                  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$o/@Price"/>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>,N/A</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:for-each>

         <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text> <!-- newline -->
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```